# Libgdx viewport not stretching

Tags: java, android, libgdx, viewport, stretching

I'm currently having a problem creating a stretchedViewPort in libgdx.
As you can see in the image I added the gamescreen is not stretched over the whole screen and there are black spaces. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.
I provided the relevant parts of the code below.

Furthermore I also tried to use asign the viewport in to the stage in the oncreate function like this: m_stage = new Stage(m_viewport); But in that case I got a black screen and nothing was rendered (tough there were no compile errors).

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing.
Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Cavasta

[image: Example]

```
package com.block.it;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;

public class GameMenu implements Screen {

    private BlockIt m_blockIt;
    private Texture m_btexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("mainmenu1.png"));
    private Image m_background = new Image(m_btexture);
    private Texture m_starttexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/c_start.png"));
    private Image m_startGame = new Image(m_starttexture);
    private Texture m_optionstexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/c_controls.png"));
    private Image m_options = new Image(m_optionstexture);
    private Texture m_highscoretexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/c_highscores.png"));
    private Image m_highscore = new Image(m_highscoretexture);
    private Texture m_continueTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/c_resume_game.png"));
    private Image m_continue = new Image(m_continueTexture);
    private Texture m_playerIcon = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("player/player_move_front.png"));
    private Image m_player = new Image(m_playerIcon);
    private int m_buttonPressed = -1;

    private boolean m_gameInProgress = false;

    private StretchViewport m_viewport;
    private PerspectiveCamera m_camera;
    private Stage m_stage = new Stage();

    public GameMenu(BlockIt blockIt, boolean gameInProgress) {
        m_blockIt = blockIt;

        m_camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        m_viewport = new StretchViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), m_camera);
        m_viewport.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
        m_stage = new Stage();

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        if (!m_gameInProgress) {
            m_startGame.setX(227);
            m_startGame.setY(270);
            m_startGame.addListener(new ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    // m_blockIt.startNewGame();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    // switch to a new texture
                    /*Texture newTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("buttons/c_new_game.png"));
                    m_startGame.setDrawable(new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(newTexture)));
                     */
                    m_player.setX(-64);
                    m_player.setY(300);
                    m_stage.addActor(m_player);
                    m_buttonPressed = 0;
                    return true;
                }
            });

        } else {
            m_continue.setX(227);
            m_continue.setY(270);
            m_continue.addListener(new ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                }


            });

        } 

        m_stage.addActor(m_background); //adds the image as an actor to the stage

        if (m_gameInProgress) {
            m_stage.addActor(m_continue);
        } else {
            m_stage.addActor(m_startGame);
        }

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(m_stage);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        m_camera.update();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); //sets clear color to black
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //clear the batch

        m_stage.act(); //update all actors
        m_stage.draw(); //draw all actors on the Stage.getBatch()
    }



    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height
    ) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {    
    }

}
```

Comment: try `m_stage = new Stage(m_viewport);`

Comment: If I try that, I just get a full black screen not even showing anything.

Comment: Viewports are not designed to work with a PerspectiveCamera. Use OrthographicCamera, or write a custom Viewport subclass.

Comment: Okay, so that fixes the problem of the black screen. But the screen still isn't stretched over the whole screen. It's still like in the image displayed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the camera and viewport to the value u used to program the world:
eg. If your world is 800*480:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(800,480);
fitViewport = new FitViewport(800, 480, camera);
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks! (passing the values to the constructor)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the viewport when the window is resized:

```
@Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    m_viewport.update(width, height, true);
    }
```

Comment: That does not fix it. I still have the same issue.

Comment: As Tenfour04 said, use OrthographicCamera instead. It works for me.